# carouFredSel in conjunction with pretty Photo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to place Pretty photo into CarouFredSel but I am having problems with what I think is conflicting jquery. Everything is working ok, but when I implement Pretty photo in the caraouFredSel collapses looking as if each li has no width or height.

I have very basic knowledge of javascript and I am currently trying to resolve the problem but would really appreciate it if I could get a hand as the deadline is closing in.

Here is the page, http://www.grahamwilsdon.com/stoves/grants.html

Also here are the scripts I am using also inline with the Libraries that are downloaded

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-5.6.4-packed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function() {
// Scrolled by user interaction
    $('#foo2').carouFredSel({
        prev: '#prev2',
        next: '#next2',
        pagination: "#pager2",
        auto: false
    });
});
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="prettyPhoto main stylesheet" charset="utf-8" />
<script src="js/pretty_photo/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
</script>
```